# Kafka with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-glue

We have a Kafka service running on AWS and planning to use Athena/S3 for long term storage for our analytics data. Is it possible to use Kafka with AWS Glue service for reading from Kafka and store in s3?

Answer (score 6):

Best bet would be to use the open source Kafka Connector for S3 from Confluent as it guarantees exactly once writes to S3 even if there is a failure and restart of the service. It’s also a real time streaming integration between so data is immediately written to S3 without extra latency.

Docs are here:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html

Source code is on github:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud

Docker images here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect/

Executable packages and tarball downloads here:

https://www.confluent.io/download/

The Kafka Sink Connector for S3 is written using the official Apache Kafka Connect API so it runs in the standard Connect Distributed worker container and can horizontally scale up/down in number of tasks or instances with partitioned and parallel consumption from Kafka for high throughput.

Comment: That'll get the files into S3, but the question seems to want a Hive/Athena table definition on top of them to query, which S3 Connector does not have

Comment: Once the raw kafka log data is in S3 you can create external tables as in the examples in the “Creating Tables” section of this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/ If there is any more complex transformations or joins needed to the data before it lands in S3 then those can be done as Single Message Transforms (SMT) within the Kafka Sink Connector for S3 or using Confluent KSQL on the original Kafka topic.

Comment: The HDFS sink optionally integrates with the Hive metastore, so I think OP is looking for something similar. There doesn't seem to be an easy way way to use the HDFS sink and point to the Glue Catalog and S3, but theoretically this should be possible.

Athena recently added support for inserts, so I wonder if you could use Athena as a JDBC sink and it would would manage the catalog for you, and work at a level of abstraction above S3.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with kafka connect to connect to S3. If you want to do something with tables look at K Tables and do this within Kafka then you can still use kafk connect to move to S3. If doing this as part of ETL you may also want to reconsider your ETL tool, or add to your toolset and utilise DataBricks.